# Special characters before progress bar in CMD but not in visual-studio-code

Tags: python, cmd, visual-studio-code, progress-bar

When I run the code below in cmd, it shows these characters `[K`before the progress bar for some reason and these characters `[?25h` after the progress bar is complete.

```py
from progress.bar import ChargingBar
import time

progress_bar = ChargingBar('Loading...', suffix='%(percent)d%%', max=5)

for i in range(0, 5):
        progress_bar.next()
        time.sleep(0.5)
progress_bar.finish()
```

However, I don't understand why it shows these weird characters in the cmd because when I run this code in the terminal of Visual Studio Code, this is what it prints:

```
Loading... ████████████████████████████████ 100%`
```

And this is what it prints in `cmd`:

```
[KLoading... ████████████████████████████████ 100%
[?25h
```

Does anyone know why it happens?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the progress-bar module you're using, but those odd characters look like terminal cursor-positioning commands which `cmd` doesn't understand.

Comment: @martineau do you know how I can find out how to fix it? I tried to research but couldn't find anything. Or is this something not fixable?

Comment: There are several third-party utilities that will make Windows `cmd` respond to such commands. Information in the section on [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) in the documentation may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the VS Code terminal is fancier than the CMD terminal and thus can understand colour escape sequences (this doesn't tie into the shell you are using, hence why this is different even though you're using Command Prompt in both cases).